# SQL - How to replace Datetime value with other Datetime?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, sql-update

Before I go messing my database up, I have a quick question:

What is the SQL command to replace a datetime value with another datetime value? I'm going to replace all datetimes in a single column of my database table with '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

I'm guessing that the SQL command is like this command to replace all string values in a single column/table?:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_id = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

This is my first time replacing all DateTime values like this - YES, I have already made a DB backup, just in case!

Comment: You already have the answer, just run it.

Comment: SQL's one of those "the more you specify, the less you get" situations. If you don't add any kind of 'where' filtering, by default the query will operate on everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to counter Joe's.  In short, **go for it**.  Also, you don't need to explicitly write out 00:00:00.

```
drop table if exists testdt;
create table testdt (dt datetime);
insert testdt select curdate();

update testdt set dt = '0000-00-00';

select * from testdt;
```

Output:

```
dt
-------------------
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Note: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

> MySQL also permits you to store '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date” (if you are not using the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode). This is in some cases more convenient (and uses less data and index space) than using NULL values.

If you use a date outside the [valid range](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) of '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31', MySQL in all its wisdom will let you store it, and even use it!

```
drop table if exists testdt;
create table testdt (dt datetime);

insert testdt select curdate();
update testdt set dt = '0000-00-00';

insert testdt select '0010-01-01';
insert testdt select '1010-01-01';
insert testdt select '1000-00-00';
insert testdt select '0000-01-01';
select *, adddate(dt, interval 999 year) from testdt;
```

Output (the invalid dates with month=day=0 are unusable)

```
dt                    adddate(dt, interval 999 year)
0000-00-00 00:00:00   NULL
0010-01-01 00:00:00   1009-01-01 00:00:00
1010-01-01 00:00:00   2009-01-01 00:00:00
1000-00-00 00:00:00   NULL
0000-01-01 00:00:00   0999-01-01 00:00:00
```